# arranging views in a circular shape titanium appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am new to titanium development. I would like to create a view like this [image](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-Radial-Social-Share-Buttons-with-jQuery-socialCircle/). when a user taps the share button another view needs to be animated in a way that it did in that link.  any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the Path menu. Here is a complete code to use it with Titanium:

https://github.com/iantearle/Push-Pin

Comment: yes thats exactly what i want. but how do i use it in my alloy projects.

Answer (score 1):

You have severals options to achieve this :

- If you use `View`, you can set a `backgroundImage` with a transparent PNG to have a round `View` or without `backgroundImage` you can use `borderRadius` to have round `View` (i suggest you to use this module for Android, to have a smooth `borderRadius` : http://gitt.io/component/com.miga.roundview)
- If you use `ImageView`, juste add the round image into `image` property

For the animation, you can use `animate` method of the View or ImageView : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-method-animate

You have a few example here : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Animation to use Animation